# ROS package for enthernet-based phantom omni

Tags: ros, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to make an ethernet-based omni work on ROS. It seems all the packages are for firewire versions. Does anybody know how to run an omni on ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/182471/ros-package-for-enthernet-based-phantom-omni/) by [Hossein](https://answers.ros.org/users/19386/hossein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-07-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TRS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4314/trs/) on 2015-01-28**:
I'm also interested in this solution - did you find one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have it up and running. I found some documentation that stated the connection can be done without connection to the internet, but i could not figure out how, but with the connection it worked.

What i did was to install the driver for the Phantom Omni device. After installing the driver i set up the ethernet ports on my computer. Be sure the computer is on the internet either with cable or wireless. This connection should just be the standard connection setup, Automatic (DHCP) on my pc at least. After that i connected Omni device  via the ethernet cable, and went  to network connections, the IPv4 settings and set the Method type to Link-Local only. Then opening the configuration executable in the driver folder i could pair the pc and the Omni.

This has been tested, and is working with this ROSnode: https://github.com/danepowell/phantom_omni

---

Originally posted by [mhessels](https://answers.ros.org/users/21777/mhessels/) with karma: 16 on 2015-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [freelist](https://answers.ros.org/users/23925/freelist/) on 2015-09-18**:
Can you please give us more details about your version of ROS, your linux distribution and some other relevant details? We are trying to use the Geomagic Touch device with the node that you said, but it seems working in a strange way, we can e.g. retrieve only encoders values and not the position..

**Comment by [mhessels](https://answers.ros.org/users/21777/mhessels/) on 2015-09-18**:
I used Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 i think. Everything just worked when the driver was up and running. I tested it with the test program in the driver folder for the Geomagic Touch device, and it gave the coordinates for the TCP with no complaints

**Comment by [freelist](https://answers.ros.org/users/23925/freelist/) on 2015-09-18**:
Ok.. thanks for the information.. and what about the OpenHaptics API verion? v3.0 or v3.4? because I think that here is the problem, we are using v3.4 (the only one available now) instead, all other examples on internet and ros nodes, worked with v3.0 that supports only firewire devices..

**Comment by [mhessels](https://answers.ros.org/users/21777/mhessels/) on 2015-09-18**:
I was using v3.1.

**Comment by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on 2015-12-27**:
excuse me, mhessels.
Did you mean you cloud use danepowell/phantom_omni pkg with ethernet-based phantom omni?